# Boost property tree (XML) remove blank lines

Tags: c++, xml, boost, formatting, boost-propertytree

I am using `boost::property_tree` to read and write xml configuration files. I want to change the value of some tags in my code and write them back to file, with some reasonable xml formatting (new lines, indenting, etc.).

Currently I am using

```
std::fstream fs("filename");
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
bpt::xml_parser::read_xml(fs,pt);

// replace value
pt.erase("tagname");
pt.put("tagname",newval);

bpt::xml_parser::xml_writer_settings<char> xmlstyle(' ',4);
bpt::xml_parser::write_xml("filename",pt,std::locale(),xmlstyle);
```

But it seems that every time a tag is deleted, it leaves behind a blank line and after some iterations the xml becomes unreadable. Is there a way to remove empty lines from the property tree itself or from the resulting xml file using boost?

I know there are other ways of removing the newlines by reading and parsing the entire file again, but I was hoping for a more convenient one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it looks like the answer was already out there on Stack Overflow, I just hadn't found it (newlines were not mentioned in the post)

[boost::property_tree XML pretty printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572550/boostproperty-tree-xml-pretty-printing)

The solution is to **read** the file with `boost::property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace`

Answer (score 2):

Not Boost, but blank lines in particular. 
You can use `std::regex_replace()` on the output before it is written to the file, removing the blank lines, like this

```
std::regex_replace(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(fout), text.begin(), text.end(), std::regex("(\\n+)"), "\n");
```

With `fout` as the file output stream and `text` as the output data as a `std::string`.

This replaces every newline followed by another newline w/o any characters in between with a single newline.

Comment: I see how your regex would replace redundant new lines in case you have a file output stream and the text given as a string. But as far as I understand i don't have either of those in the above code sample, so how would I make this work with the sample code from my question?

Comment: I see you already found a solution, but I'm still going to elaborate on this because it could be useful at some point. You begin by extracting the file contents into a `std::string text` and then declaring a `std::stringstream sstream`. Then you call the above function but pass the string stream instead of the file stream. Finally, you call `read_xml()` with the string stream instead of the file stream.

Comment: Your answer helped me because I want to preserve whitespace (particularly newline) on input, and then format the output neatly.  I modified your code to do this: `boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<std::string> settings('\t', 1);
std::ostringstream text_out;
boost::property_tree::write_xml(text_out, tree, settings);
std::ofstream fout("filename", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
const std::string & text_str = text_out.str();
std::regex_replace(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(fout), text_str.begin(), text_str.end(), std::regex("(\\n([ \\t]*\\n)+)"), "\n");
`