# boost property tree adds empty line with write_xml()

Tags: c++, boost-propertytree

I am using boost (version 1.70.0) property tree. If I have this XML (no empty lines):

```
<Root>
  <SomeOtherElement>..</SomeOtherElement>
  <Collection>
     <Item Attr1=".." attr2="" />
     <Item Attr1=".." attr2="" />
  </Collection>
</Root>
```

and I extract a node, insert to another (empty) tree:

```
auto node = pt.get_child("Root.Collection");
ptree new_pt{};
new_pt.put_child("Collection", node);
std::ostringstream os;
write_xml(os, new_pt);
auto xml = os.str();
```

I will get the output with empty lines, something like this:

```
  <Collection>



     <Item Attr1=".." attr2="" />
     <Item Attr1=".." attr2="" />
  </Collection>
```

I have tried different things. I can fix it by iterating over **Item** elements and adding one by one. Then it works, no extra lines. However, if **Item** element itself has a child element(s), then again, it will add a bunch of empty lines.

Comment: Could you please a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: The code above should do it. You just need to add includes, like, boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp. Sorry, I had a typo there before, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's duplicated with this one, or it's just a bug in the property tree.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614372/1292791

To read with the trim flag will fix the problem:

```cpp
pt::read_xml(filename, tree, boost::property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace);
```

To write with pretty format:

```cpp
pt::write_xml(os, tree, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 1));
```