# How do I delete all xml child nodes of a node which has multiple instances using boost c++

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I'm new to boost xml parser and need some help. I want to delete Price node of each Book in the below example.
I was able to delete Author of all the books. But was able to delete price of only one book. How do I delete Price of the books present?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_utils.hpp>


int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"(
<BookData>
   <Book><Author>A1</Author><Name>B1</Name><Config><Price>C1</Price><Model>M1</Model></Config></Book>
   <Book><Author>A2</Author><Name>B2</Name><Config><Price>C2</Price><Model>M2</Model></Config></Book>
   <Book><Author>A(n-1)</Author><Name>B(n-1)</Name><Config><Price>C(n-1)</Price><Model>M3</Model></Config></Book>
   <Book><Author>A(n)</Author><Name>B(n)</Name><Config><Price>C(n)</Price><Model>M4</Model></Config></Book> 
</BookData>
)");

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    read_xml(iss, pt);

    
    for (auto& node : pt.get_child("BookData")) {
        std::cout << "Child node of BookData: " << node.first << std::endl;
        node.second.erase("Author");
        
    }
    
     for (auto& node : pt.get_child("BookData.Book")) {
        std::cout << "Child node of Book: " << node.first << std::endl;
        if(node.first == "Config" ) {
            std::cout << "Erasing Price" << std::endl;
            node.second.erase("Price");
        }  
    }
    
    write_xml(std::cout, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
}
```

Output:

```
Child node of BookData: Book
Child node of BookData: Book
Child node of BookData: Book
Child node of BookData: Book
Child node of Book: Name
Child node of Book: Config
Erasing Price
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BookData>
    
   
   
   
    

    <Book>
        <Name>B1</Name>
        <Config>
            <Model>M1</Model>
        </Config>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>B2</Name>
        <Config>
            <Price>C2</Price>
            <Model>M2</Model>
        </Config>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>B(n-1)</Name>
        <Config>
            <Price>C(n-1)</Price>
            <Model>M3</Model>
        </Config>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>B(n)</Name>
        <Config>
            <Price>C(n)</Price>
            <Model>M4</Model>
        </Config>
    </Book>
</BookData>
```

From the above output I could see that only one Book is returned. How do we get all the books?

Comment: Please note that Boost does **not have** an XML library. See instead https://stackoverflow.com/q/9387610/85371

Answer (score 1):

`pt.get_child("BookData.Book")` will not iterate over all `Book` nodes. It will take the first `Book` node and then just get its children nodes and iterate over them.

Instead you should iterate through all children of `BookData` (i.e. `Book` nodes) and delete `Price` nodes from `Book.Config`:

```
for (auto& node : pt.get_child("BookData"))
{
    if (node.first == "Book")
    {
        std::cout << "Erasing Price \n";
        node.second.get_child("Config").erase("Price");
    }
}
```

Also, it seems you get empty lines in your `write_xml` output, you can trim extra whitespace while reading to avoid those extra lines ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67995964/4688321)):

```
read_xml(iss, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace);
```

Answer (score 1):

A safe variant of child deletion:

```cpp
void delete_all_occurence(boost::property_tree::ptree & tree, auto const & child, auto &&... rest)
{

    if constexpr (sizeof...(rest) > 0)
    {
        auto range = tree.equal_range(child);
        for( auto it = range.first ; it != range.second ; ++it )
        {
            delete_all_occurence(it->second, std::forward<decltype(rest)>(rest)...);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        auto it = tree.find(child);
        while (tree.not_found() != it)
        {
            tree.erase(tree.to_iterator(it));
            it = tree.find(child);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss( /* ... */ );

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    read_xml(iss, pt);

    delete_all_occurence(pt, "BookData", "Book", "Config", "Price");
}
```